Puzzling performance of join with very little rows in output. Why a bunch of seq scans are so much faster
A lot of things puzzle me in following two plans. The queries should be semantically equivalent.
Join with 'pre-filtering' forced.
select * from (select * from call_archive where 
  i1 in (SELECT i1 FROM gg) or 
  i2 in (SELECT i2 FROM gg) OFFSET 0) c
inner join gg g on c.i1 = g.i1 and c.i2 = g.i2 
order by i6 limit 100 offset 2000;
                                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=2943883.18..2943883.18 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=6805.991..6805.994 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=2943882.87..2943883.18 rows=123 width=32) (actual time=6621.736..6621.739 rows=0 loops=1)
         Sort Key: call_archive.i6
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Merge Join  (cost=2831323.14..2943878.61 rows=123 width=32) (actual time=6621.726..6621.729 rows=0 loops=1)
               Merge Cond: ((call_archive.i1 = g.i1) AND (call_archive.i2 = g.i2))
               ->  Sort  (cost=2830755.24..2868255.24 rows=15000000 width=24) (actual time=5098.789..6084.830 rows=10000489 loops=1)
                     Sort Key: call_archive.i1, call_archive.i2
                     Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 332792kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on call_archive  (cost=244.80..427633.80 rows=15000000 width=24) (actual time=39.878..2447.719 rows=10001041 loops=1)
                           Filter: ((hashed SubPlan 1) OR (hashed SubPlan 2))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 9998959
                           SubPlan 1
                             ->  Seq Scan on gg  (cost=0.00..104.32 rows=7232 width=4) (actual time=13.169..13.440 rows=4115 loops=1)
                           SubPlan 2
                             ->  Seq Scan on gg gg_1  (cost=0.00..104.32 rows=7232 width=4) (actual time=13.145..13.419 rows=4115 loops=1)
               ->  Sort  (cost=567.90..585.98 rows=7232 width=8) (actual time=0.607..0.789 rows=4115 loops=1)
                     Sort Key: g.i1, g.i2
                     Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 321kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on gg g  (cost=0.00..104.32 rows=7232 width=8) (actual time=0.012..0.255 rows=4115 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.202 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 39
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 1.315 ms, Inlining 8.851 ms, Optimization 129.593 ms, Emission 83.789 ms, Total 223.549 ms
 Execution Time: 6837.762 ms
(26 rows)

The 'naive' join:
select * from call_archive  c                                                                                                                                
inner join gg g on c.i1 = g.i1 and c.i2 = g.i2 
order by i6 limit 100 offset 2000;
                                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=159448.99..159448.99 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=57304.054..57304.056 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=159448.57..159448.99 rows=165 width=32) (actual time=57296.356..57296.358 rows=0 loops=1)
         Sort Key: c.i6
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=18.01..159442.50 rows=165 width=32) (actual time=57296.346..57296.348 rows=0 loops=1)
               ->  Seq Scan on gg g  (cost=0.00..104.32 rows=7232 width=8) (actual time=0.015..1.875 rows=4115 loops=1)
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on call_archive c  (cost=18.01..22.02 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=13.921..13.921 rows=0 loops=4115)
                     Recheck Cond: ((g.i1 = i1) AND (i2 = g.i2))
                     ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=18.01..18.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=13.903..13.903 rows=0 loops=4115)
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on btreeidx1  (cost=0.00..8.87 rows=674 width=0) (actual time=6.168..6.168 rows=162811 loops=4115)
                                 Index Cond: (i1 = g.i1)
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on btreeidx2  (cost=0.00..8.88 rows=675 width=0) (actual time=7.567..7.567 rows=188048 loops=4115)
                                 Index Cond: (i2 = g.i2)
 Planning Time: 0.230 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 9
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 0.603 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.349 ms, Emission 7.368 ms, Total 8.320 ms
 Execution Time: 57304.772 ms
(19 rows)

The first one consistently outperforms the second in case where there are very little rows in the result (0 in this example). Yet optimizer chose second.
Looking at plans, it makes even less sense. The first plan is bunch of seq scans. The second is bitmap index scan in the loop. So, the chosen one looks obviously better.
Can someone enlighten me. Does it have something to do with data fitting in RAM/cache locality?
How do you nudge query optimizer to more likely use something like first plan?

The optimizer guesses the row counts wrongly. Try an index on call_archive (i1, i2).

Thank you for hinting in right direction
